# How to rewrite the intersection of one set with the the union of some arbitrary number of other sets.

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

This question stems from this statement contained in an answer to a different question:

> Observe that $P(A\setminus B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$. Therefore
>
> $$ \begin{aligned}
>  P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)&=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n
>  A_i\right)+P\left(A_{n+1}\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\\
>  &=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)+P(A_{n+1})-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n
>  (A_i\cap A_{n+1})\right). \end{aligned} $$

Ok, so what I don't understand is how the last doesn't read

$$=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)+P(A_{n+1})-P\left(A_{n+1}\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^n
 A_i) \right)$$

based on the "observe that" statement in the preface. If these are equivalent statements, my question is how do I understand and show that? It seems like the author of the answer skipped a pretty big step (at least for someone like me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersections and unions distribute over each other: e.g.

$$ \bigcup_{\iota \in I} (X_i \cap Y) = \left( \bigcup_{\iota \in I} X_i \right) \cap Y$$

for any set $Y$ and family of sets $X_i$.

Answer (score 1):

i apologise if this isn't helpful but i think this wouldnt be counted as a comment either.
but your first line 
$$ \begin{aligned}
 P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)&=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n
 A_i\right)+P\left(A_{n+1}\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\\
 \end{aligned} $$

so lets think of it in a different way. let $E = A_{n+1}$ and $F=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}$
then what we have is
$$P(F \cup E)= P(F)+P(E \setminus F)$$
which by youre own statement you accept.
applying the arguement: $P(A\setminus B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$
gives
$$P(F \cup E)= P(F)+P(E)-P(E \cap F)$$
which again makes sense as this is just the inclusion-exclusion principle. we know that intersections and unions are distributive so
$$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}) \cup A_{n+1})= P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_{i})= P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i})+P(A_{n+1})-P(A_{n+1} \cap (A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup ...\cup A_{n}))$$
$$= P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i})+P(A_{n+1})-P((A_{n+1} \cap A_{1})\cup (A_{n+1} \cap A_{2})\cup ...\cup A_{n+1} \cap A_{n}))$$

$$=P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i})+P(A_{n+1})-P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(A_{n+1}\cap A_{i}))$$